# Can I delete a facebook friend using a facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

is there a way to delete a friend using the facebook open graph api?
If not, do you have any other idea how to enable a user to delete a friend from within my application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot programmatically delete a user's Facebook friends. The potential for abuse is too great.

Comment: is this still the case, has anything changed since 2010?  Can it be done with a dialog?

Comment: To my knowledge, @NappingRabbit, this can still not be done programmatically.

Comment: Exactly the functionality I'm looking for for my current facebook app(not anything abusive). Too bad its gone. One idiot does something stupid and rest of the good ideas have to face the consequences too.