# Using Linkedin/Facebook API to remove a contact

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am planning to use linkedin/Facebook API in my enterprise application.
I just wanted to know that :

1. Can i remove a user from my contact list using the linkedin API.
2. Can i unfriend someone or remove him from my page using Facebook API

Regards,
Abhishek Ranjan

Answer (score 2):

For Facebook, it's not possible via the current Graph API. (See also [Can I delete a facebook friend using a facebook api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355044/can-i-delete-a-facebook-friend-using-a-facebook-api))

I don't know LinkedIn API, but an old (2009) example I see from a quick google search revealed

> Examples of LinkedIn APIs HTTP DELETE - Remove > Remove a friend
>   DELETE http://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/123/friends/456 > Delete

Hope that tidbit of info from http://www.slideshare.net/linkedin/building-consistent-restful-apis-in-a-highperformance-environment helps.

Comment: That is a theoretical example, based on the model, but doesn't work in practice because it's unimplemented.

Comment: Do you have any better examples that you can share with Abhishek?

Comment: No. If the feature was implemented what you shared would be the right syntax.

Comment: Ok, it's confirmed then.  You cannot delete friendships in neither LinkedIn nor in Facebook with their current APIs.

Answer (score 2):

The LinkedIn API does not currently support removing connections from your network.